# Select rows group by date

Tags: mysql, select, group

I want to select headings (and ID-s) from table grouped by date but to looks like below.

[image]

Left cell is `ID`
Right cell is `heading`
Middle cell is `date`

SELECT `ID`, `heading`, `date` FROM `news` GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date` DESC;

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is ``ORDER BY `date` DESC, `heading` DESC`` and then process them as groups in your client application. What is the tabular output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I Just want to list like above is on picture. List rows grouped by date... (Showing date and rows belongs to date).

Comment: Then, as I said before, that is something you do at application level (display logic). For example, in your application code you would only display a new date row (or heading, or whatever element) if the current row's date is different to the previous row's date. What is your end goal? Are you outputting an html page? What language are you using?

Comment: Can you share your table structure and some sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

To display a group by value as a header in MySQL, you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function in combination with the `CONCAT` function to concatenate the group value with a string. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Group:', group_column) AS header, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY group_column;
```

In this query, replace `group_column` with the name of the column you want to group by, and your_table with the name of your table. The `CONCAT` function combines the string "Group:" with the value of group_column to create the header. The `COUNT` function is used to count the number of rows in each group.

This will produce a result set with two columns: the header column and the count column. The header column will display the group value concatenated with the string "Group:".

Comment: never heard of option to show group field as header

Comment: SELECT CONCAT('Group:', group_column) AS header - this is fine, but I don't want to COUNT how many rows are in the group, but to list them as well.